# Improper Functioning of sql to tbl conversion

Tags: java

I want to convert a sql file containing insert statements to a corresponding tbl file. I have tries the code given below. It works well but I need a blank line after each record i.e a blank line has to be present in between processing to two insert statements.

Input:

```
 --------------------------------------------------
 PRINT ''
 PRINT 'Inserting data into table post_tran...'
 PRINT ''
 --------------------------------------------------
 GO
INSERT INTO 
 post_tran(post_tran_id,tran_nr,datetime_tran_local,system_trace_audit_nr,settle_
 amount_rsp,settle_tran_fee_rsp,post_tran_cust_id,prev_post_tran_id,next_post_tra
 n_id,message_type,tran_postilion_originated,sink_node_name,settle_entity_id,batc
 h_nr,tran_completed,tran_type,rsp_code_rsp,auth_type,auth_reason,retrieval_refer
 ence_nr,settle_amount_req,settle_tran_fee_req,settle_currency_code,datetime_req,
 recon_business_date,realtime_business_date,acquiring_inst_id_code) VALUES(  
 1,2,'2002-04-02 19:02:28','008497',4120,10, 2, 0,0,'0200', 0, 'LinkSink', 
 1,1,0,'01','01','00',0,'000000000102',6000,0,'840', '', '2004-02-11 
 12:00:00', '2004-02-11 12:00:00', '2200017000')


 INSERT INTO post_tran( 
 post_tran_id,tran_nr,datetime_tran_local,system_trace_audit_nr,settle_amount_rsp
 ,settle_tran_fee_rsp,post_tran_cust_id,prev_post_tran_id,next_post_tran_id,messa
 ge_type,tran_postilion_originated,sink_node_name,settle_entity_id,batch_nr,tran_

   completed,tran_type,rsp_code_rsp,auth_type,auth_reason,retrieval_reference_nr,se
 ttle_amount_req,settle_tran_fee_req,settle_currency_code,datetime_req,recon_busi
 ness_date,realtime_business_date,acquiring_inst_id_code) VALUES( 2,2,'2002-
 04-02 19:02:28','008497',4120,10, 2, 0,0,'0200', 1, 'LinkSink', 
 1,1,0,'01','01','00',0,'000000000102',6000,0,'840', '', '2004-02-11 
 12:00:00', '2004-02-11 12:00:00', '2200017000')
```

Output:

```
[name] post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 1[/data]
[name]tran_nr[/name]=[data]2[/data]
[name]datetime_tran_local[/name]=[data]2002-04-02 19:02:28[/data]
[name]system_trace_audit_nr[/name]=[data]008497[/data]
[name]settle_amount_rsp[/name]=[data]4120[/data]
[name]settle_tran_fee_rsp[/name]=[data]10[/data]
[name]post_tran_cust_id[/name]=[data] 2[/data]
[name]prev_post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 0[/data]
[name]next_post_tran_id[/name]=[data]0[/data]
[name] post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 2[/data]
[name]tran_nr[/name]=[data]2[/data]
[name]datetime_tran_local[/name]=[data]2002-04-02 19:02:28[/data]
[name]system_trace_audit_nr[/name]=[data]008497[/data]
[name]settle_amount_rsp[/name]=[data]4120[/data]
[name]settle_tran_fee_rsp[/name]=[data]10[/data]
[name]post_tran_cust_id[/name]=[data] 2[/data]
[name]prev_post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 0[/data]
[name]next_post_tran_id[/name]=[data]0[/data]
```

Required Output:

```
[name] post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 1[/data]
[name]tran_nr[/name]=[data]2[/data]
[name]datetime_tran_local[/name]=[data]2002-04-02 19:02:28[/data]
[name]system_trace_audit_nr[/name]=[data]008497[/data]
[name]settle_amount_rsp[/name]=[data]4120[/data]
[name]settle_tran_fee_rsp[/name]=[data]10[/data]
[name]post_tran_cust_id[/name]=[data] 2[/data]
[name]prev_post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 0[/data]
[name]next_post_tran_id[/name]=[data]0[/data]

[name] post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 2[/data]
[name]tran_nr[/name]=[data]2[/data]
[name]datetime_tran_local[/name]=[data]2002-04-02 19:02:28[/data]
[name]system_trace_audit_nr[/name]=[data]008497[/data]
[name]settle_amount_rsp[/name]=[data]4120[/data]
[name]settle_tran_fee_rsp[/name]=[data]10[/data]
[name]post_tran_cust_id[/name]=[data] 2[/data]
[name]prev_post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 0[/data]
[name]next_post_tran_id[/name]=[data]0[/data]
```

Code:

```
 public class SqlToTblCovertor {

private File source_folder = null;
private File destination_folder = null;
private String source_absolute_path = null;
private String destination_absolute_path = null;
private String absolute_file_name = null;
private String absolute_new_file_name = null;
private List<String> column_name_list = null;
private List<String> column_values_list = null;

public SqlToTblCovertor(String source_folder_name,
        String destination_folder_name) {
    source_folder = new File(source_folder_name);
    destination_folder = new File(destination_folder_name);
    source_absolute_path = source_folder.getAbsolutePath();
    destination_absolute_path = destination_folder.getAbsolutePath();
    column_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    column_values_list = new ArrayList<String>();
 }

 public void run() throws IOException {
    validateInputs();
    migrateFiles();
 }

 private void validateInputs() {
    if (source_folder.isDirectory() == false) {
        displayMessageAndExit("Source must be a FOLDER");
    } else if (destination_folder.isDirectory() == false) {
        displayMessageAndExit("Destination must be a FOLDER");
    }
 }

 private void migrateFiles() throws IOException {
    String[] file_list = source_folder.list();
    for (String file_name : file_list) {
        migrateFileContains(file_name);
    }
 }

 private void migrateFileContains(String file_name) throws IOException {
    absolute_file_name = source_absolute_path + File.separator + file_name;
    absolute_new_file_name = destination_absolute_path + File.separator
            + getNewFileName(file_name);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(new File(absolute_file_name))));
    String line_info = br.readLine();
    StringBuffer new_query = new StringBuffer("");
    while (line_info != null) {
        new_query.append(convertQuery(line_info));
        line_info = br.readLine();
    }
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(absolute_new_file_name));
    fw.write(new_query.toString());
    br.close();
    fw.close();
 }

 private String convertQuery(String query) {
    String new_query = "";
    if (query.startsWith("INSERT")) {
        int round_bracket_start = query.indexOf('(');
        int round_bracket_end = query.indexOf(')');
        int round_bracket_start_after_values = query.indexOf('(',
                round_bracket_end);
        String query_column_name = query.substring(round_bracket_start + 1,
                round_bracket_end);
        String query_column_values = query.substring(
                round_bracket_start_after_values + 1, query.length() - 1);
        covertColumnNameList(query_column_name);
        covertColumnValueList(',' + query_column_values + ',');
        new_query = createNewQuery() + "\n";
    }
    column_name_list.clear();
    column_values_list.clear();
    return new_query;
 }

 private void covertColumnNameList(String query_column_name) {
    String[] column_list = query_column_name.split(",");
    for (String column_name : column_list) {
        column_name_list.add(column_name);
    }
 }

 private void covertColumnValueList(String query_column_values) {
    if (query_column_values.equals(",")) {
        return;
    }
    String column_value = null;
    int comma_index = query_column_values.indexOf(',');
    int next_comma_index = 0;
    if (query_column_values.charAt(comma_index + 1) == '\'') {
        int quote_index = query_column_values.indexOf('\'', comma_index);
        int next_quote_index = query_column_values.indexOf('\'',
                quote_index + 1);
        next_comma_index = query_column_values.indexOf(',',
                next_quote_index);
        column_value = query_column_values.substring(comma_index + 2,
                next_comma_index - 1);
    } else {
        next_comma_index = query_column_values
                .indexOf(',', comma_index + 1);
        column_value = query_column_values.substring(comma_index + 1,
                next_comma_index);
    }
    column_values_list.add(column_value);
    covertColumnValueList(query_column_values.substring(next_comma_index));
 }

 private String createNewQuery() {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
    if (column_name_list.size() != column_values_list.size()) {
        display("Error : " + absolute_file_name);
    } else {
        display("Migrate : " + absolute_file_name);
        for (int index = 0; index < column_name_list.size(); index++) {
            buffer.append(createNewColumn(column_name_list.get(index),
                    column_values_list.get(index)));
        }
    }
    displayFileInformation();
    return buffer.toString();
 }

 private void displayFileInformation() {
    display("Column Name :" + column_name_list);
    display("Column Values :" + column_values_list);
    display("\n");
 }

 private String createNewColumn(String column_name, String column_value) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
    buffer.append("[name]");
    buffer.append(column_name);
    buffer.append("[/name]=[data]");
    buffer.append(column_value);
    buffer.append("[/data]");
    buffer.append("\r\n");
    return buffer.toString();
 }

 private String getNewFileName(String file_name) {
    String new_file_name = "";
    int dot_index = file_name.indexOf('.');
    new_file_name = file_name.subSequence(0, dot_index) + ".tbl";
    return new_file_name;
}

private static FileWriter log_file = null;

private static void display(String message) {
    try {
        if (log_file == null) {
            File file = new File("d:\\config_migrator_output.log");
            file.deleteOnExit();
            log_file = new FileWriter(file);
        }
        log_file.write(message + "\n");
        log_file.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in generating log file.");
    }
}

private static void displayMessageAndExit(String message) {
    display(message);
    System.exit(0);
}

private static void showUsages() {
    displayMessageAndExit("java ConfigMigrator <source-folder> <destination- 
 folder>");
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 2) {
        showUsages();
    }
    SqlToTblCovertor config_migrator = new SqlToTblCovertor(args[0], 
  args[1]);
    try {
        config_migrator.run();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new line after reading each insert.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(absolute_new_file_name));
while (line_info != null) {
    String convertQuery = convertQuery(line_info);
    if(convertQuery.isEmpty()) {
        line_info = br.readLine();
        continue;
    }
    new_query.append(convertQuery);
    new_query.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    fw.write(new_query.toString());
    new_query.setLength(0);
    line_info = br.readLine();
}
```

Also write directly into file to avoiod out of memory error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It worked. Can you please answer my one more question which i have posted here .Please do go through my that question. Question Tittle " Get first two lines from a file put it into hasmap as key and whole file as value of hashmap.And write hashmap to a file  "